# How to set editText visible/invisible?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, radio-button

In my program I want to be able to hide the edit text when a radio button is check and then reappear when the user clicks the other radio button.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.waist2height); {
        final EditText h = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);          
        final RadioButton rCM = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioCM);
        final RadioButton rFT = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFT);                       
        if(rCM.isChecked()){    
            h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);              
        }
        else if(rFT.isChecked()){               
            h.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }}
```

The code below is where i have the problem i only added in the relevant part of my code instead of the entire thing

```
if(rCM.isChecked()){                    
    h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                  
}
else if(rFT.isChecked()){                   
    h.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work.
Am I missing anything? Or have I got it all wrong altogether?
I have tried `h.setVisibility(View.GONE);` however it just ruines the format of the xml.

Comment: Did you use setOnCheckedChangeListener in your radio button?

Comment: Use a listener event to trigger the visible methods and not a variable!

Comment: This must be work .. provide your code here then we can get to find issue

Comment: ive added the relevant parts instead of the entire thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a sample and it works for me just take a look at this code :

I've declared those variables as global

```
RadioButton rb1,rb2;
TextView tbHideOrNot;
```

Then in my `onCreate()` I've got this :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    tbHideOrNot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                tbHideOrNot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rb2.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                tbHideOrNot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rb1.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

In my opinion, that's not a good idea use a `RadioButton` for the use that you want, I recommend you to use `CheckBox` cause you can only click **ONE** and this you have to check if the first `RadioButton` is clicked and you press the second one you'll have to uncheck the first, etc... well It's your code I'm only giving to you an advice, this code is working for me, let me know if it works for you :)

By the way if you want to use this code :

```
if(rCM.isChecked()){                    
 h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                  
}
else if(rFT.isChecked()){                   
 h.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

It's fine but you only will hide or not the `TextView` when you start the `Activity` and you'll have to put any `RadioButton` (if you want) `android:checked="true"` or `false` if you want to be showed or not the `TextView`, but with this code you won't get the click event on the `RadioButtons`.

Answer (score 3):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId==0){

                h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else if(checkedId==1){

                h.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: it dosnt seem to work, maybe because of the (checkedId == 0)?

Comment: First of all he's using `RadioButton` not `RadioGRoup`, second if you read the [RadioGroup documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html#onCheckedChanged(android.widget.RadioGroup,%20int)), when the checkbox is cleared checkedid is -1.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this :

```
rCM.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
rFT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    h.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);              
}
});
```